# Django: ManyToManyField creates duplicate column name

Tags: django, django-models

I have two types of users in my application: `auth.User`, which comes from django.contrib.auth (the standard Django authentication module) and `mysql.User`, which is in my own module.  In addition, `mysql.User` inherits from an abstract model.  The whole thing looks similar to this (some fields were omitted for brevity):

```
class Resource(Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True
  owners = ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='%(class)s_owners')

class User(Resource):
  name = CharField(max_length=16)
  host = CharField(max_length=64)

class Database(Resource):
  name = CharField(max_length=64)
```

As you can see, I want to make it so that multiple `auth.Users` may "own" a given `mysql.User` and a given `mysql.Database`, hence the ManyToManyFields.  However, when I go to run `./manage.py syncdb` I get the error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'user_id'")
```

Indeed, `./manage.py sql mysql` shows the source of the error (again, some columns and ALTER TABLE statements omitted for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE `mysql_database` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`server_id`, `name`)
);
CREATE TABLE `mysql_user` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `host` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`server_id`, `name`, `host`)
);
CREATE TABLE `mysql_database_owners` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `database_id` integer NOT NULL,
    `user_id` integer NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`database_id`, `user_id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `mysql_user_owners` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `user_id` integer NOT NULL,
    `user_id` integer NOT NULL, -- <<<<< here is the conflict >>>>>
    UNIQUE (`user_id`, `user_id`)
);
```

Notice how the intermediate table for Database is created without a naming conflict but the table for User has a conflict.  I don't see where a ManyToManyField provides a way for one to provide column names in the intermediate table, but unfortunately I think that's what I need.

Another method I tried was to explicitly create the intermediate table and use the `through` option of ManyToManyField, like so:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True
  owners = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='%(class)s_owners', through='Owner')

class Owner(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='Resource_owners')
  resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource)
```

But then I get this error:

```
 AssertionError: ForeignKey cannot define a relation with abstract class Resource
```

Which is to be expected with Django.

So, short of renaming `mysql.User` to something like `mysql.DBUser`, is there any way to avoid the naming conflict created by Django?

Comment: i guess you don't want to define the owners M2M relationship separately on User and on Database, and specify the through table for the User-User relationship; hence loosing the advantages of abstraction (although maybe you could define an "owners" property on Resource). An other (crazy) idea: set "through" to '%(class)Owner' and define both M2M models: UserOwner and DatabaseOwner. I really don't think it works, though...

Answer (score 0):

How about creating the many to many table separately, avoiding the use of the ManyToMany field?  You could use a manager or method to return a list of users for a given resource and visa versa.

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    ...

   class Meta:
      abstract = True

   def owners(self):
       return ResourceOwner.objects.filter(resource=self)


class ResourceOwners(models.Model):
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
      abstract = True
```

Comment: That was one of my first attempts, but you can't have a ForeignKey relationship to an abstract model.  In other words, Resource can't be abstract in this proposed method.